# Broadcast on local network ok, or will it get blocked?

Tags: networking

I have a system that works on a local network and the nodes self-discover each other via a packet broadcast system, similar to how DHCP works.

Can I expect that this will work on most normal unix LANs, or do some distributions have **default** settings that block non-standard network broadcasts? If so, what are these settings, and how do I turn them off?

Note I am not concerned about weird situations in which some administrator has deliberately configured their LAN to block broadcasts. I am concerned with default settings.

Comment: It's more about the switches that make up an L2 segment, and not the (unix/linux/windows) hosts themselves. Nearly all switches will forward broadcasts by default. Usually, (unix/linux/windows) hosts don't.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what does "normal unix LANs" mean, but broadcasts should cover whole L2 segment (aka broadcast domain).

It is possible to block broadcasts on some smart L2 devices but there is no "standard policy" about it and such devices are unlikely to run unix.

One may also block broadcasts on local firewall (`iptables/netfilter` in linux) but I do not think any distro does it by default.